# Correlations and PCA for use in a SDM - use of background points?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a series of environmental data layers in r that I am trying to do a PCA on to reduce dimensionality for my SDM (species distribution model). I am attempting to do this in R in order to run maxent with the dismo package.
All of the papers I have read that do this technique do not give much detail regarding how to accomplish this. My specific questions are as follows:

1. when you look for correlations between variables and run a PCA, do you use both presence and absence/background points together or do correlations/PCA for each separately? I assume it is the former but I want to make sure before I code it.
   I used both to make a correlation plot with the pairs() function, but if I use both presence and absence points for the PCA how will I extract the values of the principal components at my presence points only?
2. Regarding absence points, I am using background points for maxent, so they are not true absence points. Therefore I can select as many points as I want and I’m finding confounding information regarding how many points to use. Maxent uses 10,000 by default - should I be using 10,000 in my correlation and PCA?